# Shopify schema settings image use in template (need to know syntax)

Tags: image, schema, settings, shopify

I have defined this in schema.json :

```
{
        "type": "image",
        "id": "zeva_image_1",
        "label": "Image"
      }
```

And i need to use it in a template and i am doing it like this :

```
<img src="{{ settings.zeva_image_1 | asset_url }}" />
```

But its not working out for me.

can anyone help in correcting this ?

Answer (score 3):

## 1st Method

If you want to use the type "image"  then you should put the file extension too.

```
{
  "type": "image",
  "id": "zeva_image_1.jpg",
  "label": "Image"
}
```

and

```
{{ 'zeva_image_1.jpg' | asset_url | img_tag }}
```

## 2nd Method

Also you can use the "image-picker" type like

```
   {
    "type": "image_picker",
    "id": "zeva_image_1",
    "label": "Image"
  }
```

with

```
{{ settings.zeva_image_1 | img_url: 'master' | img_tag }}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped :)

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept my answer if that helped you :)

Comment: @mash R - is there a way to set "default" value for image_picker?

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic - Just checked the documentation again, Don't think its possible.

Comment: if using `{{ settings.zeva_image_1 | img_url: 'master' | img_tag }}` how does one pass a class name to that image?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It help you

```
<img src="{{ section.settings.zeva_image_1 | img_url: 'master' }}" />
```